# Joomla 1.7 DB Query does not work when query has an ampersand

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, ampersand

I am getting mental on this.  I have tried everything so far, for hours. Here is the task:

In a module override, I use this code:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$title = "Analysen & Auswertungen Infos";
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE title=\"$title\"";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadRow();
echo $result;
```

This  works, but since I am getting the `$title` dynamically from a variable I need this to work:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$title = "$linktext Infos";
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE title=\"$title\"";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadRow();
echo $result;
```

I have 6 variables that populate `$linktext` in a foreach loop, all work except the one with the string including the "&"...

I tried htmlentities and utf8_encode and different kind (actually all combinations) of " and ' in the query... nothing worked.

Whe I use the following sql query in phpmyadmin it works:

```
SELECT `introtext` FROM `x999x_content` WHERE `title`="Analysen & Auswertungen Infos"
```

I am really puzzled over this, and right now very tired and angry...
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a good long sleep is the best you can do!

I just used `strlen` to check the length of `$linktext` (which I get from DB via a foreach loop) and found that it is longer than the visible chars. This is logical because of the `&` which is returned as `&amp;`.

In order to use this `$linktext` inside a new DB query, all I needed to do was to decode the html entity:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
// this is the correct way of doing it
$title = html_entity_decode($linktext)." Infos"; 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE title=\"$title\"";
$db->setQuery($query); 
$result = $db->loadRow();
```

or any other combi for the query (",',`,$query->select ) as pointed out in the other answers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$title = $linktext." Infos"; 
$query = "SELECT `introtext` FROM `#__content` WHERE `title`='".$title."'"; 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$result = $db->loadRow(); 
echo $result;
```

I don't know if it'll work but, I never have any problems and this is how I write my code.

Comment: yeah... did try everything... ",',` ... just to be sure i tried your way as well. it didnt work. all other $linktext work though! with my and your solutions. its just this single one containing an "&"... this is really spooky. maybe it has to do with the $linktext i am getting from DB? maybe there is some kind of wring character in it... but i tried htmlentities and similar on $linktext as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE title=\"$title\"";
```

For this:

```
$query = $db->getQuery( tru );
$query->select( 'introtext' );
$query->from( '#__content' );
$query->where( 'title=' . $db->Quote( $title );
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: nope, same as above... all other $linktext work, except the one with the & in it... but thanks for trying!

Comment: btw, 2 typos:
line1 should be ( true )
and
line4 missing one ) right before ;

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$keyvalue='101';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE keyfield='".$keyvalue."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result && $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $fsql='DESCRIBE mytable';
  $fresult = $conn->query($fsql);
  if($fresult){
    while($frow = $fresult->fetch_assoc()) {
      $fieldname=$frow['Field'];
      echo($fieldname . ' = ' . $row[$fieldname] . '<br><br>');
     }
  }
}else echo("Failed: " . $sql);

?>
```

Comment: You do realise that this question was asked 6 years ago. Right?